# Generating n random bits in Java

Tags: java, security, bit

I've been toying around with java's security module as I'm looking into encryption.
I have a question regarding generating a random amount of n bits.

Say I want to generate.. 1000 bits.
I use the following code:

```
BigInteger num = new BigInteger(1000, new SecureRandom())
```

When I print this I get a large decimal value, however my problem comes when I go to count the bits. I plug the decimal value from "num" into a Decimal to Binary converter. When I count the amount of characters (1s and 0s bits) the amount isn't always 1000. Sometimes it's 997, 996 etc. My question is, why does this happen and how can I solve the issue? Is the decimal value still 1000 bits?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I suspect the first bits could be 0s..

Comment: `10` is a random 4-bit base-2 number. Oh, you don't agree? Is `0010` better? It's the same number. --- For decimal numbers, is `99` a 2-digit number, or a 3-digit number without a leading zero?

Comment: Ok, I see, So is the problem arising with leading 0s?

Comment: 1000 was an example by the way, Its happened with a few other values e.g, 1021

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 1000 bit string with the high order bit set to 1 you can do the following:

```
String b = null;
try {
    b = "1" + SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().ints(999, 0, 2)
            .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ne) {
    ne.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(b.length());
System.out.println(b.substring(0,10)
```

Prints something like

```
1000
1110110001
```